# MySQL installation help

Tags: java, mysql, database, configuration, installation

I do Java EE 6 programming since not long ago. For my application server i use glassfishV3.0.

I decided not to use the derby/JavaDB that it came with the glassfish download,so i am moving to MySql database.

I am a bit confused, i think i should install MySql 5+, but which one?

5.1

...

or 5.5(This one seem to be the latest one).

Could you recommend me which one i should choose.
And also it would be very handy a podcast, video or similar.. tutorial for the installation.

Just one more doubt:
I do my programming in a winXP work station, is there any compatibility problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the Community Edition, 5.5 is the latest so go with that.

[Download here](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/).

[Installation instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/installing.html).

[Using mysql with Java](http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/).

Comment: Thank you very much im sure that was a great help